# Haskell written telnet echo server does not process exit command

Tags: haskell

I am writing a TCP telnet Haskell terminal which code so far is

```hs
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

import Control.Concurrent (forkFinally)
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import Control.Monad (unless, forever, void)
import qualified Data.ByteString as S
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString (recv, sendAll)

main :: IO ()
main = runTCPServer Nothing "3000" talk
  where
    talk :: Socket -> IO ()
    talk s = do
      msg <- recv s 1024
      unless (S.null msg || ob msg) $ sendAll s msg >> putStrLn (C.unpack msg) >> talk s
    ob msg = msg == (C.pack "exit\n")

-- from the "network-run" package.
runTCPServer :: Maybe HostName -> ServiceName -> (Socket -> IO a) -> IO a
runTCPServer mhost port server = withSocketsDo $ do
    addr <- resolve
    E.bracket (open addr) close loop
  where
    resolve = do
        let hints = defaultHints {
                addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]
              , addrSocketType = Stream
              }
        head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) mhost (Just port)

    -- Generate Socket
    open :: AddrInfo -> IO Socket
    open addr = E.bracketOnError (openSocket addr) close $ \sock -> do
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
        withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
        bind sock $ addrAddress addr
        listen sock 1024
        return sock

    -- Loop
    loop :: Socket -> IO b0
    loop sock = forever $ E.bracketOnError (accept sock) (close . fst)
        $ \(conn, _peer) -> void $
            -- 'forkFinally' alone is unlikely to fail thus leaking @conn@,
            -- but 'E.bracketOnError' above will be necessary if some
            -- non-atomic setups (e.g. spawning a subprocess to handle
            -- @conn@) before proper cleanup of @conn@ is your case
            forkFinally (server conn) (const $ gracefulClose conn 5000)
```

with the dependencies

```
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.16.4.0
                    , network ^>=3.1.4.0
                    , bytestring
```

And when I start the server and telnet into it and proceed to type `exit` and press space the server does not close the connection which I expect it to do.3

I have tried to use `"exit\n\n"`, `"exit\n"`, and `"exit"` as the value to compare in the `ob msg` line none of them have worked.

Comment: Instead of guessing, maybe you should print the value of `msg` to see what it contains when you type "exit".

Comment: There are no messages in TCP. It's a stream of bytes.

Comment: @jthulhu I did, it just prints: exit and two new lines

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI And it is split by new lines, as show my testing

Comment: @jthulhu printing with show instead of unpack says it is using windows newlines

Comment: What @n.m.couldbeanAI meant I think is that you try to compare the `msg` variable with a predefined string, as if the `msg` variable contained a single message, whereas it just contains the first 1024 bytes of the concatenation of every message sent to the server so far that haven't been processed yet. This means that if I send twice the exit message, `msg` will contain twice "exit". Assuming you properly handle that, you should probably trim `msg`.

Comment: (1) You might be seeing that chunks you get from `recv` correspond to lines typed by the user, but that's by no means guaranteed. You need to extract the lines out of the stream if you want any reliability. (2) In telnet protocol, lines are terminated by `\r\n`, not by `\n`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Why they use windows termination?, It was not written in UNIX?

Comment: Telnet was written for networks of the time, not for Unix. Unix didn't even exist back then, not speaking of Windows.